# How to scrape data from different pages and assign to same dataset?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a website with scrapy, where the item_id along with some data is on one page and additional information from this item on another page.

The issue I am facing, how to assign the additinal information to the same dataset found on page1?

item:

```
class GetIt(scrapy.Item):
    ID         = scrapy.Field()
    name         = scrapy.Field()
```

The relevant part of my crawler:

```
rules = (

        Rule( # first page
            LinkExtractor(allow=['regex']), 
            callback='parse_1'
        ),
        Rule( # second page
            LinkExtractor(allow=['regex']), 
            callback='parse_2'
        ),

        Rule( # index pages
            LinkExtractor(allow=['regex']), 
            follow=True
        ),
    )

    def parse_1(self, response):
        GetIt                    = GetIt()
        GetIt['ID']              = response.xpath('regex').re_first('regex=(\d+)')
        return item

    def parse_2(self, response):
        GetIt                   = GetIt()
        GetIt['name']           = response.xpath('regex').extract()
```

So the idea is, if rule fires, he extracts the new item, if rule 2 fires, he found a page that contains further info of items. Rule 3 gets all the pages from an index site.

So the info is on page type 1:

/maininfo.html

The secondary info to the items on type 2:

/search.php?itemid=303

On page type 1 there is the link to pagetype 2, so I can extract link and ID.

In theory I could also just call the page directly in the parser function:

```
url2 = response.xpath('code').extract_first() # get the link
scrapy.Request(url2, callback=self.parse_unitpage) # get the name from 2nd page
... somehow like this
```

Would this be possible? And if not, how to merge the data of page type1,2 if the ID belongs to the same dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure I fully understood what you want, but as far as I understand at the first page you get the `ID` and on the second you get `name`. This is how I would do that:

```
def parse_1(self, response):
    item = GetIt()
    item['ID'] = response.xpath('regex').re_first('regex=(\d+)')
    url_to_get_name = ...

    yield Request(url_to_get_name, self.parse_2, meta={'item': item})

def parse_2(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    item['name'] = response.xpath('regex').extract()

    yield item
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Could you please expain the code? I would like to understand how you did this.

Comment: @merlin when you are on the page with `ID` data, you create an item (`GetIt()`) and then just pass it to the next callback, which will parse page with `name` data. Note the `meta` argument in `Request` constructor and `meta` attribute in `response` object.

Comment: The last part with meta=..  is what I do not understand. You declare in parse_2 an item of type response.meta. The docu states: "The dict passed in this parameter will be shallow copied2". What does this mean?